# Deploy Java app to Openshift v3 with local code changes

Tags: java, openshift

I have a query about deploying git or non-git java applications to remote (on premise) Openshift v3 without always doing git commits.

I have my local java app (based on fabric quickstarts) working locally with minishift, without doing a git commit. So, if I wish to deploy to remote  Openshift, I would like to verify my changes work before in a remote dev environment before committing the changes. Unfortunately, I don't always have minishift to verify code changes locally.

I looked at using Openshift deployment on IntelliJ, although I was able to connect to Openshift V3, I got an error: Deploy of this source to this Openshift version is not supported.

Any suggestions would be appreciated to speed up development time.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the checkout of your Git repository, run:

```
oc start-build myappname --from-dir=.
```

This will package up the local source directory and send it directly up to OpenShift and use that for the build, rather than source code being pulled down from the hosted Git repository.

This will only work for the single build. Do the same again after next lot of changes.

To revert back to what is in the hosted Git repository, start a new build using:

```
oc start-build myappname
```

or trigger the new build from the web console.